# phonegap app with PHP sessions or alternative login methods

Tags: php, ios, mysql, mobile, phonegap

I'am using PHP/MySql to store user logins for a web platform. Now I would like to offer a mobile App using phonegap. 
What I know is how to use Ajax requests to get stored database information from remote scripts like PHP files in the App. But how can I secure these App access like I do on the web page with PHP Sessions/Cookies?

Comment: Do some research, come up with your own solution and ask for help if your solution isn't working. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done, sorayadragon. My Idea is to do it with PHP server sessions but in my opinion its not the best way cause you do not secure the mobile files, just the ajax requests. Spare your words, when your answer doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I will do it with LocalStorage: Login via AjaxRequest against serverside MySQL DB authentication / PHP Sessions ans store the username and serverside generated SessionID in LocalStorage. On every Pageload, I have to check these values against a serverside running Login-Check-method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently creating a system where I login via an Ajax request. On the server side, the session is created and I return the sessionid, such as..

```
'session_id' => session_id()
```

then save that to localstorage. I don't see how this is any less secure than when your browser creates the phpsessid in a cookie in your browser.